# Python - Should I use in ThreadPoolExecutor as an argument ("max_amount_of_threads" - 1)?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

in my app I am using this code:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
executor.submit(partial(self.determine_file_type, text_file_path))
```

as a way to not get my app frozen when I am importing files. It is working nicely, but I started to wonder.

If my understanding of this ThreadPoolExecutor and threads in general in any CPU is correct, then shouldn't it be better to instead of using `5` as an argument use something like ("max_amount_of_threads" - 1)?

I heard that it is possible with python to actually get amount of threads in given machine but I am wondering if it will be working on all cpus? Including mobile ones on android? Is it a smart thing to do or I am mistaken?

EDIT:

Current code:

```
    try:
        thread_count = len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)) - 1 if len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)) > 3 else 3
    except (AttributeError, NotImplementedError):
        thread_count = os.cpu_count() - 1 if os.cpu_count() > 3 else 3
```

Comment: You won't get any benefit by using the maxiimum amount of threads. Use a finite amount like 10 or 50 or something that isn't going to hog the entire machine. Remember also that neither the disk nor the network is multi-threaded, so you may not get any benefit at all beyond the 1 background loading thread required to keep your GUI alive.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. But my point is exactly to not kill the machine AND the GUI. So I want to actually use all the threads - 1 so I will get as much speed (kinda of course) without freezing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. `os.cpu_count()` - gets number of CPUs on the system, doesn't always work and returns `None` when that's the case
2. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` - Same, but raises an exception instead of returning `None`
3. `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))` - This one tells you how many *usable* CPUs are available (when processes have affinity restricted to a subset of cores). Can raise `NotImplementedError` when the feature isn't available.

If you want to autoscale, I'd suggest trying #3, catching the exception if it fails and trying #1/#2, and if that fails, use some small reasonable hard-coded number of threads. Or just omit the argument entirely and let `ThreadPoolExecutor` decide how many threads to launch (it typically chooses a number somewhat above the number of cores, since threads are assumed to be I/O bound and most of them are expected to spend most of their time blocking on I/O, not trying to consume a core; as of 3.8/3.9 it uses `min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)`, but that's changed before). Given the GIL, the number of cores usually doesn't matter much anyway; you're either I/O bound (and cores aren't taxed) or CPU bound in Python code (GIL restricts you to one core). The only exception is extension modules that release the GIL while doing heavy CPU work, and that's not the case for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wanted to ask, if I try to use `len(os.sched_affinity(0))` I get error `Cannot find reference ... in init.py`. I am using python 3.8. I thought you maybe meant `os.sched_getaffinity` but after reading description it doesn't look like that?

Comment: @Peksio: That was a mistake (forgot it when searching too, thus thinking it was undocumented; oops). Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I edited my post with my current code. I also added `AttributeError` in exceptions because I read that python on some systems have this `sched_getaffinity` and for example on macos it is throwing `AttributeError`. But currently it seems to be working fine. Thank you